# Python request post on local website

Tags: python, post, python-requests, screen-scraping

I've been trying to scrape [this local website](https://ww2.stj.jus.br/processo/pesquisa/?aplicacao=processos.ea) and search for a simple integer
on "Número do Processo na ORIGEM" field. Currently running the following code to no success:

```
headers = { 'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'browserName': 'mozilla',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://ww2.stj.jus.br/processo/pesquisa/?aplicacao=processos.ea',
}

r = requests.post('https://ww2.stj.jus.br/processo/pesquisa/?aplicacao=processos.ea/', data={'idNumeroOriginario':'123'}, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)

print r.content
```

It appears to me that the search never gets posted. I have also tried changing from data=... to json=..., following requests instructions.

Any hints on how to solve that?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you means by "local"?

Comment: from my city, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Do a network analysis in the developer tool of your browser when you pressing the button and copy the curl command of the POST package.

Then you surf to [curl.trillworks.com](https://curl.trillworks.com/) and convert the curl command it into a Python POST request.

Inside of your python request you can modify the values.

Comment: That's really nice. Thanks for the tip!